# What is the difference between data validation and data cleaning, And what arethe connections and similarities between them?

Tags: validation, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm studying data science. I looked other references to get an clear answer to this. But no success  with that. Can someone explain me about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data cleaning** may include removing typographical mistakes or approving and redressing values against a known run down of entities. A few data cleaning arrangements will clean data by cross checking with an approved data set.

**Data validation** might be strict.

Example: While submitting any form user enter special characters in name fields. like K@v!ndu. And you want to store only string in db.
So you are using a function which remove the special characters before storing name. So in db the name will be save as Kvndu. This process of removing special characters is **Data cleaning**.

And If you implement some functionality to check that name field should have only string value. To do that you will apply some validation on name field. This process is called **Data validation**.

I had used name field just for example and **Data validation** can be a part of **Data cleaning**. Like you have remove the special character and using validation for numbers.
Both process allow to save only string in your db.